# NetConnection unhandled NetStatusEvent

Tags: actionscript-3, events, actionscript, red5, netconnection

Occasionally I'm getting an unhanded `NetStatusEvent` when using `NetConnection` to connect to a Red5 server:

```
Error #2044: Unhandled NetStatusEvent:. level=error, code=NetConnection.Call.Failed
```

This is how I am connecting (the only place where `NetConnection.connect()` is called):

```
public function Connect(callBack:Function = null):void 
{
    if (IsConnected())
    {
        if (callBack != null) 
        {
            callBack.call();
        }
    }
    else // Not connected
    {
        netConnect.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, function(e:NetStatusEvent):void
        {
            // OnConnect called whenever there is a net status event
            OnConnect(e, callBack);
            netConnect.removeEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, arguments.callee);
        });

        try
        {
            // Attempt to connect to Media Server
            netConnect.connect(MEDIA_SERVER_URI, true);
        }
        catch(error:Error)
        {
            logger.LogError("NetConnection.connect threw an exception.", error);
        }
    }
}
```

I am adding an event listener for `NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS`.  How is it possible that sometimes my listener called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're removing your listener in your `NetStatusEvent` handler. You should keep it until the connection is closed. This is why `NetStatusEvent` is only handled once before its listener is removed. Any other than first event will throw that error.

So remove `netConnect.removeEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, arguments.callee);`

`NetConnection` dispatches that event quite a lot, depending on what is happening. You have to handle the event until every time. For a list of possible values of the `info` property visit this [Link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/NetStatusEvent.html#NET_STATUS). There's also a little example of how to handle the event at the end of the page.

Comment: So multiple NET_STATUS event could be fired during one NetConnection.connect() call?

Comment: `connect()` call fires 1 event with an array of possible `info` properties, but even after connection your `NetConnection` object can fire `NET_STATUS` events for `AppShutdown`, `Close`, `NetworkChange` or some of other stuff that's going on with the connection. So you should definitely leave a listener untouched until `NetConnection` is closed.

Comment: Ok thanks!  My `Connect()` function above might be called regularly.  If I take out the `removeEventListener`, it would start to trigger multiple anon functions.  I cannot handle this event in my constructor either, because I need the callback passed into `Connect()`.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you've already handled that by checking the `isConnected()` method of yours, but I don't know why don't you use the `connected` property of the `NetConnection` class instead. Another thing you can do is add the `removeEventListener` just before the `addEventListener` and name your anonymous function (to make it removeable from outside). Note that `removeEventListener` won't throw an error even if your `NetConnection` object doesn't have a listener.

Comment: The connection regularly drops, so the IsConnected() check won't prevent multiple anon functions from being added to the listener.  I could try the removing before adding.  Otherwise I could keep to my above code, but include a second listener in the constructor to pick up straddling NET_STATUS events. This will basically do nothing (maybe just a log entry). Thanks for your replies

Answer (score 1):

You may see this if your client does not handle the onBWCheck or onBWDone methods. This will also happen if you have bandwidth detection turned on; turn it off on the server by changing this parameter in the red5.properties file and restart the server.

```
rtmp.bandwidth_detection=false
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  We are using Red5 0.9.1 (sorry, I should have specified that in my question).  I believe bandwidth detection is only from version 1 onward?

Comment: In the case of 0.9, you probably just need to add onBWDone

Answer (score 1):

> Blockquote

Just an additional piece of information.  Dispatching NetStatusEvent objects with info.level = "error" will always throw an Unhandled Exception.  Its a special use case.  I, for example, wrap all of this functionality and change the level to "info" before re-dispatching the event.